# When I am posting the array data to the web method,then we get error like this Internal server error(500)

Tags: jquery, ajax

This my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "WebForm4.aspx/StatusUpdate",
    data: '{"idArray":"' + JSON.stringify(x) + '","Status":"' + Rstatus + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        location.reload();
    },
})
```

Web method

```
 Public Shared Function StatusUpdate(ByVal idArray() As String, Status As String) As String
 Dim strargument As New StringBuilder()
        Try
            Dim cnt As Int16 = idArray.Length()
            For i As Int16 = 0 To cnt - 1
                If i = cnt - 1 Then
                    strargument.Append("'" & idArray(i) & "'")
                Else
                    strargument.Append("'" & idArray(i) & "',")
                End If
            Next

            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Update [ERP_EmployeeRole] SET Status=@Status where RoleID in (" & strargument.ToString & ")")
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status)
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Dim s1 As String = "Status updated"
                Return s1
            End Using
```

Comment: A 500 error means the problem is in your server code, not the jQuery. We need to see the complete Web Method implementation to help you. Also seeing the complete error message would make pinpointing the problem easier too

Comment: It is a server side issue, please check your url and parameteres are correct or not.

Comment: i sent my total code please look at

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the way you are constructing Json data to be sent to server.

I would suggest you to make a class where you define an array of strings i.e. idArray and another string property Status like the class that I have defined below. I will use a C# version that you will be able to convert to VB.

```
public class SomeClass
{
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public string IdArray[] { get; set; }
}
```

And on client side you may use this as

```
var SomeObj = { Status: "Some Status", IdArray: YourArray }
```

and before sending it to server you should use:

```
JSON.stringify({"someObj":SomeObj});
```

and in your Web Method you should use something like this

```
public static YourMethod(SomeClass SomeObj)
{
    //TODO: Do Something here with your object
}
```